# Wifi and data keeps turning on

Tags: wi-fi, data-connection

i did a recent update off some apps a few days ago and ever since my wifi and data keeps turning on no matter  how many times i turn them off... Then on the other hand, sometimes it turns off and stays off for  while, only to turn again randomly. it's really annoying and killing my battery, plus the data usage is killing my wallet as well! i don't know what's causing it...

i'm using apex launcher and i thought it might be causing the problem (since it's recent update) but switching to my previous launcher (htc sense) didn't make a difference... i don't wanna go and delete my launcher since i've made quite some customizations and don't wanna do it all over again.

can somebody help me, please?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it's an app doing that (which is not unlikely), you'd first need to identify which app that might be. Uninstalling all of them would be a bit hard, so let's try a different approach – and narrow down the candidates.

To be able to change your device's network state, that app would need specific permissions. Which are [CHANGE_WIFI_STATE](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/perms#CHANGE_WIFI_STATE) for WiFi resp. [CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/perms#CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE) for your mobile data. So check your installed apps for those having that permission. You can do so by looking up each of them in the "my apps" section of *Google Play* – or you use a [Permission Checker](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/security_permissions#group_379).

There's e.g. [Permission Friendly Apps](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.androidsoft.app.permission), being very permission-friendly itself (requiring not a single one). It presents you with a list of all your installed apps, and even marks them according to their "permission-friendlyness". Tapping the entry of an app reveals its permissions.

[image: Permission friendly Apps] [image: aSpotCat] [image: aSpotCat]
<sup>*Permission Friendly Apps* and *aSpotCat* inform about permissions your apps request (click images for larger variants)</sup>

Better suited for our purpose here is [aSpotCat](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.a0soft.gphone.aSpotCat). As you can see in the screenshot, it lets you browse apps by permission – perfect to find your candidates.

Once you've narrowed down the list of installed apps to those having the necessary permissions, check that for apps you've recently installed or updated (i.e. just before the trouble started). Hopefully that leaves as few candidates as possible, best only one. Those you need to get rid of, at least temporarily, one by one – until your trouble ends. The last app disabled must be the one having caused the issue.

Before "kicking it" completely, check its settings. Maybe it was just a new feature introduced, and you can turn it off. If not: the app stores are full of alternatives, watch out for those. And take care of permissions *before* installing one of those ;)

Answer (score 0):

I had a recent issue with this problem that keeps turning my wifi and data on by itself. Ive tried everything including that connection optimizer which doesnt exist in my phone because im from Germany then I just decided to install AVG updated it and run a quick scan, immediately after there were several risk and the first one was an app installed which was very fishy to me so i uninstalled it the rest i just change the setting. That solved the problem. Maybe because im always downloading apps from different sites outside google play that it could have brought some malware. Im glad ive installed AVG i was already planning to factory reset my Note 5.