# Find a malicious app

Tags: wi-fi, nexus-5, safe-mode

I have a Google Nexus 5.

Recently i had a problem about WI-FI, it just could not be turned on. I've found many suggestions how to fix that. None of them but turning on in safe mode solved the problem.

As i know, safe mode disables third party apps, which potentially can cause a problem.

I wonder how can i detect exactly which app caused wifi problem ?

What i think now is brute force approach, that is, to delete all the apps one by one and see what happens.

Comment: Can I ask how are you sure that WiFi problem is related to an app?

Comment: @SarpSTA I'm not sure. It is related to Safe Mode and as safe mode disables apps, i thought that it was related to app

Comment: You can begin with listing out all the apps which have the permission `android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE`. You may  use Izzy's [answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/95491/96277) to list those app in fewer steps or my command-line based [answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/123100/96277).

Answer (score 0):

Do a brute force approach, but not by uninstalling apps one by one. Do it  in the  permission control. First go to settings, then go to permission control, then go to wifi and then uncheck app one by one . This may be woks